# Wikipedia Scraper using Python

Tags: python, nlp, beautifulsoup, urllib2, wikipedia

Hi I am trying to build a simple wikipedia scrapping tool that can let me analyse the text and build a timeline of the events in the life of a person using python. I have searching the net for possible methods to do it and until now i have been able to retrieve the data using BeautifulSoup and urllib2. The code till now looks something like this:

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
import nltk
import json


#get source code of page (function used later)
def fetchsource(url):
    source = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    return source

if __name__=='__main__':
    #url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=raw&title=Tom_Cruise" #works
    url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&&titles=Tom_Cruise" #works
    print url
    source = fetchsource(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
    print soup.prettify()
```

Now although i can work with this, but the output that i get is a little tricky to parse and i just wanted to ask if there is a better way to do or maybe a more manageable syntax in which i can retrieve the data.
Kindly comment.

Comment: You don't need BeatifulSoup to parse the returned (valid) XML, you will need to soup only the contents of the revision.

Comment: Or you might want to use the [`action=render` parameter](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#cite_ref-5) directly on the article instead of using the revisions query-api.

Comment: i tried with 
url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=render&title=Tom_Cruise"

but it doesnt work for me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use [pywikipediabot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikipediabot) to get the article wikitext. For example, to get the wikitext of Tom Cruise, like in your example, you can use:

```py
import wikipedia

page = wikipedia.Page(wikipedia.getSite(), 'Tom_Cruise')

pageText = page.get()

print pageText
```

This way you can try to get the data from templates, and there are some parsers for wikitext, if needed.

Comment: Furthermore, a list of Python libraries that provide access to Wikipedia through its API can be found here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Python

Answer (score 2):

Extracting data from html pages is never fun, but http://scrapy.org/ makes it much easier in my opinion. You can use XPath to extract data, which is quite powerful. If you want to retrieve the data that way, I would definitivly use scrapy.

You should also check if there are other options to get the data. As far as I know, it's possible to download a data dump of wikipedia. That might be overkill for your use case, but other APIs might exist.

Comment: working with a complete dump would be too much of a hassle considering i only need pages with respect to a couple of people at max. Still looking for other api options.

Comment: Then give scrapy and XPath a try.

Comment: i will definitely have a look. Thank you.

Comment: I second Scrapy--it takes a little bit of time to learn to use, but it's extremely powerful and configurable.

Answer (score 2):

DBpedia allows structured information in Wikipedia to be retrieved through a query.
http://dbpedia.org/